# HighCharts ios Disable Initial Animation

Tags: ios, swift, highcharts, data-visualization

I tried the following:

```
 let s_animation = HIAnimation()
 s_animation.duration =  2000
plotOptions.series.animation = s_animation
```

later this one :

```
plotOptions.series.animation= false // incompitable type
```

and

```
plotOptions.series.animation.duration = 0 // the app crashes
```

get stuck for several hours. Is there any solution

Comment: `series.animation` is a `HIAnimation` type, not a `Bool`. Why would you set it to `false`? Did you try `plotOptions.series.animation = nil`?

Comment: thanks for reply. but throws me following error after adding nil
`Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: Here is related issue requested on GitHub repository: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-ios/issues/120

Answer (score 1):

The HighCharts docs are out of date.  Though it does say that you can set the animation options to false, this is not actually true.

I think you were close in your implementation, though; the crash was caused by the fact that .series and .series.animation are both nil until you create those plot option objects.

The best (and currently only) way to do this is as follows:

```
plotOptions.series = HISeries()  // you would set plotOptions.line = HILine() for a line chart
let animation = HIAnimationOptionsObject() // Even though their docs say HIAnimation(), it's the options you can set the duration for
animation.duration = 0 // actually disables the animation, but there is still some lag from view loading and the chart loading, so it will kind of just blip in after a split second.
plotoptions.series.animation = animation
```

Hope this helps.